# Disadvantage of using multipart form

Tags: html, forms, multipartform-data

I was wondering if there is any disadvantage of adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to a form when there's no file input field.

I declare the form in a template and I only need multipart on some pages.
Should I always add it or only when I need it?

Will the request be bigger? Or are there any other consequences (except for decreased readability in Firebug / DevTools)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the request be bigger?

Slightly.

> Or are there any other consequences (except for decreased readability in Firebug / DevTools)?

No.